# preview-latex generates .png previews but does not place them in the buffer

Tags: emacs, preview, aquamacs

When generating previews, I get a small, empty white box with a border around it. I looked inside the .prv folder and the .png files are indeed being created. emacs has support for .png (e.g. image-dired and image-view-mode correctly display them).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$3+4$
\end{document}
```

I've tried AUCTeX 11.86 (with the patch described here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=646632 which fixes a gs error by changing some flags), the latest development version, which includes the patch, and the version packaged with Aquamacs 2.4, since in Aquamacs.app, preview-latex works fine.

emacs 24.1.1 under X with ghostscript 9.05, texlive-2011, on OS X 10.7.

Comment: I get the regular preview (no patch to AUCTeX). Mac OS X 10.5, though.

Comment: @egreg what version of emacs and ghostscript do you have? Is this under X, or did you compile Emacs.app?

Comment: It's the regular Aquamacs 2.4; GPL Ghostscript 9.05. Oh, sorry! I read the question as a problem with Aquamacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to the latest Xquartz, which broke preview in all emacsen, including Aquamacs - I was now getting the notorious road-block sign. gs was returning an error from the latest Freetype 2, which is distributed with X11 on OS X. I downgraded to 2.4.8 (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=137638) and all emacsen work.

There's no telling anymore what was causing the initial error I was having.

EDIT: I'm using the latest dev version of auctex, but the stable version works as well so long as you patch preview.el so that it sends proper flags to gs.